# Distributions of infinite sums of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(Z_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the arrival times of a Poisson process of intensity $1$ on the interval $[0,\infty)$, i.e. $Z_i \sim \text{Gamma} (i,1)$. We define $X = \sum _{i \in \mathbb{N}}  Z^{-2}_{i} $.

Also, let $(Y_i)$ be the arrival times of another Poisson process independent of the first one and define $Y= \sum _{i \in \mathbb{N}}  W^{-2}_{i} $.

I want to show that $X+Y$ has the same distribution as $cX$, for some constant $c$.

(As far as I tried, conditioning doesn't seem to work, as we have to condition on infinitely many random variables.)

Comment: You should use the fact that the superposition of two independent Poisson processes of rates $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ is again Poisson with rate $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$.

Comment: Also, if $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are arrival times of a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$, then the scaled times $\{bA_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ look like arrivals of a Poisson process of rate $\lambda/b$ (assuming $b>0$).

Comment: @Michael I don't quite understand how can we rigorously use the superposition fact to prove this statement. Can you show me how to handle the infinite sum?

Comment: Let $\{H_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be the arrival times of the sum process, which is identically distributed to the arrival times of a Poisson process with rate $1 + \lambda$ (assume the rate of the second stream is $\lambda$, as that was not given). Note that each $H_i$ corresponds to a single arrival of either $Z_j$ or $W_k$.

Comment: In looking back at your question, I think editing is needed since the notation is weird.  I think the second stream should have $(W_i)$ arrival times, not $(Y_i)$.